# How to print Footer on all pages without overlapping with the body content?

Tags: html, css, footer, overlapping

I am trying to print the footer on all the pages including the page number but didn't find any solution. I tried using `#footer{position: fixed; bottom:0;}`, body content is overlapping with the footer during print.

Comment: Depends on what you consider a "page" -- a web page doesn't have a concept of a printed page; if you are thinking of what a web browser visually displays, what if the user maximizes their browser?  If viewed on a mobile device, what if they tip it 90°?

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin-bottom to the content equal to the height of footer that will ensure that there will be an empty space between the body content and footer.